# Systemd cgroup flag passed, but systemd support for managing cgroups is not available - Docker error

Tags: linux, docker, containers, systemd, cgroups

I had installed `docker` in my aws linux machine a while ago and was using it for `kong` testing purposes,
Machine details:
Linux `ip-172-31-10-102 4.9.70-22.55.amzn1.x86_64` #1 `SMP` Wed Dec 20 `23:36:28` `UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Today when i tried to run normal hello-world container in my docker, i am facing the following error.

```
[root@ip-172-31-10-102 ~]# docker run hello-world
systemd cgroup flag passed, but systemd support for managing cgroups is not 
available
docker: Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: systemd cgroup flag 
passed, but systemd support for managing cgroups is not available.
ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled
```

I am not sure what configuration has messed in here,i am able to see docker info and container list everything but not able to run a container.
i tried re-installing dockers but still see the same error.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Thank you for guiding with information.